# Dynamic add column with loop

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, repeat

I'd like to create a dynamic procedure wich will generate the columns for me automatically but somethings wrong. I have to do this a few times in my program and I don't really want to do it manually.

So thats the code that I used before

```
    DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS RepeatLoopProc$$
CREATE PROCEDURE RepeatLoopProc()
  BEGIN
          DECLARE x  INT;
          DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);
          Declare @sql nvarchar(4000);
          SET x = 0;

          REPEAT
                      SET str =  '';
                      SET  str = CONCAT(str,'ossz_levon_het_',x);
                      SET  x = x + 1;
                      set @sql='ALTER TABLE telephelyi_teszt ADD '+ str +'DOUBLE NULL';

                      execute @sql;
          UNTIL x  > 50
          END REPEAT;

  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I've got a syntax error near the `Declare @sql nvarchar(4000);` line any ideas?

Comment: Missing a space between ' and double in @sql.

Comment: i fixed it but the same error at the 7-th line near the @sql declaration

Comment: What kind of project is this, That you have to create dynamic fields in a table? You should improve your normalization so that wont have to happen.

Comment: yes i know it looks like a little bit mess but i'am creating a different summarys from a soucre database and i have to transform it into the right way . So i'am using pivioting or stg like that and i have a lof of columns like the week1 resulst week2 result ect. And after all i have to creat a physic table from the querys and thats why i need them! i hope its quite clear:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When you use `DECLARE` to create local variables in a stored procedure, don't use the `@` prefix. Those are for session variables.
- But you shouldn't DECLARE the variable anyway. Prepared statements don't work with local variables, only session variables. You don't have to declare session variables.
- Your ALTER TABLE statement has an error. You didn't put a space after the column name and before DOUBLE. In other words, the statement will be like the following, which will cause a syntax error wen you execute it.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE telephelyi_teszt ADD ossz_levon_het_1DOUBLE NULL
  ```
- You didn't PREPARE the statement. You can't just EXECUTE a string as a statement. See examples in the manual on [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).
- It's probably bad design to create 50 columns in any table with identical content. Consider creating a second table, with one column `ossz_levon_het` and a reference back to your parent table `telephelyi_teszt`. This is the recommendation of [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) to avoid repeating groups of columns.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, yep, you're right. There are exceptions to every rule of course, but adding 50 columns like this is definitely a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: look my anwers upper a litte and after maybe it's more acceptable